# Receive whatsapp voice message in Twilio

Tags: audio, twilio, media, whatsapp

I want to receive voice messages from whatsapp with Twilio. The native voice message you can record with the mic next to the text input.
When I send that message, I get the message in the webhook but it is empty and with no media.
I took a look at Twilio log of that message and it says that:

### Twilio is unable to process the Content-Type of the provided URL. Please see the [Twilio Markup XML Documentation](/docs/api/twiml/) for more information on valid Content-Types.

So it seems that Twilio for WhatsApp does not support Whatsapp native audio encoding.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you!

Comment: I am having the same issue and while it says that the invalid Content Type is audio/ogg, the documentation says it is supposed to be supported.

Comment: Twilio docs say OGG is a supported filetype https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017961894-Sending-and-Receiving-Media-with-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio-Beta-

Does anyone know if this was fixed?

Answer (score 4):

I received this answer from Twilio

> Hi Gustavo‍ ,
>
> Thanks for reaching out. Audio files are currently supported through WhatsApp, but 
>   we discovered an issue with the way WhatsApp is passing the audio file
>   to us that is preventing these voice recordings from coming through.
>   WhatsApp has let us know this is something they will be addressing so
>   look for that to be addressed in the coming months.
>
> Thanks,

Hope this helps everybody

Comment: Thanks for returning to update the question. Can you send these types of message, too??

Answer (score 1):

It seems that native WhatsApp audio now works on Twilio. The parameter 'MediaUrl0' has the link to the audio, it is working for me